# WordPress: Store stripe info as user_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm using a Stripe webhook to store the dollar amount a customer is charged when they get charged in Stripe.

I've got the webhook working fine and can email out the charge amount but can't seem to store it in WordPress user_meta field.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
    $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
    $event_json = json_decode($input);

// Check against Stripe to confirm that the ID is valid
    $event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_json->id);

// If charge is successful, store in user meta
    if (isset($event) && $event->type == "charge.succeeded") { 
      $amount = $event->data->object->amount / 100;
    }
    $payment_user_id = 9192321; 
    update_user_meta($payment_user_id, 'payment_history', $amount);
```

Is this because the json received from stripe is in a format that needs to be converted to something before I can store it?  If I try to convert it to an integer using intval($amount) it just stores it as 0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I'm dumb and just needed to put the "update_user_meta" in the "if" statement.